# Responsive menu with "More" option as menu option start to overflow the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I have a navbar with 11 links, and I want it to be responsive. The goal is, as window gets narrower, a 12th link will appear as a ddl that will include the 11th element, 10th and so on. The text in links is variable in length based on language, so the links are not equal in width.

This is the example of the markup (partial).
https://jsbin.com/fijakipesu/edit?html

What is the best approach to achieve this?

[starting screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbZ6V.png)

Comment: Hi your jsbin is a bit broken so I can't see what the larger screen/start state looks like?

Comment: I`ve added a picture of the navigation bar , of how it looks on a bigger screen. And on a 320 device it will be left with 2 icons and a "more" one that opens a ddl witch includes the ones that do not fit anymore.

Comment: This is an interesting problem, I've never tried to progressively hide links like this before. The easiest way is with css and treat them all the same; at a certain breakpoint, before the line starts breaking to two lines, create the mobile version of the menu that goes vertical instead of horizontal. It would get tedious, but if you figure out when each menu item breaks, viewport width, then you use pseudo nth-child to target each one in turn with a clear: left or something like that.

Comment: This is how i`ve started but, there is a problem , those menu items are not the same length , for example if i change the sites language. :D

Comment: I would suggest making them all the same width in that case. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this and is working like a charm. For anyone who is trying to achieve that responsive/progressive menu, try it.

http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/860LzgLL/

```
var elemWidth, fitCount, fixedWidth = 120,  
    $menu = $("ul#menu"), $collectedSet;
collect();
$(window).resize(collect);

function collect() {
    elemWidth = $menu.width();
    fitCount = Math.floor(elemWidth / fixedWidth) - 1;
    $collectedSet = $menu.children(":gt(" + fitCount + ")");
    $("#submenu").empty().append($collectedSet.clone());    
}
```

Comment: I think css is more flexible as javascript is

Comment: This will have a problem with events attached to elements that are "moved" in and out of the sub-menu that are then "emptied".

Answer (score 0):

Create the buttons and then hide it for desktop users and show the complete navigation.
With `@media` you can show the buttons and hide the navigation items for mobile devices.

When the user clicks on the button or hover it, they get the navigation items.

HTML:

```
    <button class='menu-button0'>Click me</button>
    <div id='showMe'>link1, link2, link3</div>
```

CSS, when mobile device visits your page:

```
    #showMe(display:none;)
    .menu-button0:hover + #showMe{display:block;}
```

CSS, when desktop device visits your page:

```
   .menu-button0{display:none;}
```

Comment: I have tough of that , but is a i need a more flexible approach because i got tablets and big phones ,i cant resume to just two layouts

Comment: You may apply that to all of your elements. That's possible!

Comment: Remember: Tables are not responsive friendly

Answer (score 0):

I went with a variant of StefanB's as this allowed me to play with the widths of the items a little more by simply checking if the item right coord was overlapping the "menu" space....:

```
function collect() {
    $menu.children().css({"display": "block", "width": "auto"});

    var elemLeft= $menu.offset().left + $menu.outerWidth();
    $allElements = $menu.children();
    $collectedSet = $allElements.filter(function() {
        var right = $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth();
        return (right + 40) > elemLeft;
    });

    $("#submenu").empty().append($collectedSet.clone());
    $collectedSet.css({"display": "none", "width": "0"});
}
```

Alternatively, if you attach events to the li options, then you need to trigger those events (which would have been lost/not-cloned during the clone)

```
function collect() {
  $menu.children().css({"display": "block", "width": "auto"});


  $allElements = $menu.children();
  $allElements.each(function(index) {
      $(this).attr("data-original-index", index);
  });


  var menuRight= parseInt($menu.offset().left + $menu.outerWidth());
  $allElements = $menu.children();
  var show=true;
  $collectedSet = $allElements.filter(function() {
      var right = parseInt($(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth() + 140) ;
      if ( right > menuRight ) show=false;
      return !show;
  });


  $clonedElements = $collectedSet.clone();
  // Handle events attached to the original set but clicked on from the more-menu set....
  $clonedElements.on("click", function() {
      var originalIndex = $(this).data("original-index");
      var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll("#menu > li");
      menuItems[originalIndex].click();
  });


  $("#submenu").empty().append($clonedElements);
  $collectedSet.css({
      "display": "none",
      "width": "0"
  });
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/zx1rmgwq/53/ for a running example